# C#/XAML HTTPclient/webrequest GET with await never ends

Tags: c#, xaml, get, httpclient, httprequest

Why won't this HTTPHandler work? Both getPageBody and getPageContent await forever and never get back to me. Nothing else happens after the await (used a break point).

Any help would be strongly appreciated!

PS: Visiting the page in the browser does work - so the problem must be on the C# end.

```
public class HTTPHandler
{
    public static async Task<List<String>> getPageBody(String page)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
          "http://www.mywebsite.com/dev/api/" + page);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //reader.Close();
        //response.Close();

        return responseFromServer.Split(';').ToList();
    }

    public static async Task<List<String>> getPageContents(String page)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();            
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> resp;
        await (resp = client.GetAsync("http://www.mywebsite.com/dev/api/" + page)).ContinueWith(
            (getTask) =>
            {
                getTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            });
        //HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.GetAsync("http://mywebsite.com/dev/api/" + page);


        Task<String> responseBodyAsText = resp.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        responseBodyAsText.Wait();
        return responseBodyAsText.Result.Split(';').ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see why `getPageContents` has problems - you're using both `Result` and `Wait()`, which are blocking calls. Don't do that in an async method. `getPageBody` should be okay, although you should use a `using` statement to dispose of the response. Can you create a short but *complete* program demonstrating this failing? Does it fail from a console app, or only in a WPF/WinForms app?

Comment: @JonSkeet how can I fix the getPageContents then? I'd rather use the HTTPClient. It's a windows store app, basically all it has right now is a button with an onclick, which calls a function from the RPSGame class, this function calls the getPageContents (or the other, both don't work) and shows the result in a dialog <-- it should wait for the request to be finished before continuing the app.

The getPageBody doesn't work either.

If you want I can upload a quick demo of this failing.

Comment: You should *await* the tasks rather than using `Result` and `Wait`. But let's concentrate on one thing at a time - just the simpler `getPageBody` method to start with. If you can create a short but complete program demonstrating that failing, we can move on from there.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot! By trying and copy pasting I ended up with an example using .Result and .Wait -- I simply replaced them to awaits without result and etc and everything works fine! If you want, post an answer and I'll +vote it.
This is the final code
`public static async Task<List<String>> getPageContents(String page)
{
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.GetAsync("http://site.com/dev/api/" + page);
 String responseBodyAsText = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 return responseBodyAsText.Split(';').ToList();
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that further up your call stack, you're using `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result`.

If you use `Wait` or `Result` on `async` code, you run the risk of deadlock. I explain this in more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: That's right, JonSkeet already got me on the right track -- using the awaits instead of wait and result fixes the issue! Thanks for the articles.